# Failing to compile correlated Java Generics parameters with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

The following little Java example won't compile for unclear reasoning:

```
package genericsissue;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface Attribute<V> {}

interface ListAttribute extends Attribute<List<?>> {}

public class Context {
    public <T, A extends Attribute<T>> void put(Class<A> attribute, T value) {
        // implementation does not matter for the issue
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ctx.put(ListAttribute.class, list);
    }
}
```

The line with ctx.put produces following error:

```
Context.java:18: <T,A>put(java.lang.Class<A>,T) in genericsissue.Context cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<genericsissue.ListAttribute>,java.util.List<capture#35 of ?>)
```

If working without wildcards the attribute pattern works fine.

Is there any explanation why the compiler does not accept the value with wildcard typing?

Comment: It's probably a limitation of the type inference system. Try: `ctx.<List<?>, ListAttribute>put(ListAttribute.class, list)`.

Comment: Excellent formulation of your question! SSCCE, error message, etc.

Comment: Related question from last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449799/how-do-generics-of-generics-work/16451216#16451216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
public <T, A extends Attribute<T>>
```

With

```
public <T, A extends Attribute<? super T>>
```

Comment: How can you assume this is okay, given we don't know the implementation of `put`?

Comment: Is it then typesafe? Because to me it looks then like I can put all instances from the super type hierarchy as values which is not what I want to allow.

Comment: I think we can assume this is OK because you have to keep in mind that `value` could be any subclass of `T` already.  So if `value` is a `String`, `A` could be `Attribute<String>`, `Attribute<CharSequence>`, or `Attribute<Object>` as it stands now.  The only thing this will prevent is *producing* a `T` from the `A`, and that seems reasonable.

Comment: Sounds reasonable after thinking for a while. So that really is the solution and it IS typesafe because the Attribute type can stand higher in the type hierarchy. It works like a charm now.

Comment: @MarkPeters - it's OK, but it shouldn't be necessary; `T` is free enough during inference, so `Attribute<T>` should work. BTW, OP's code compiles in Java8.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, the argument type of `list` is not really `List<?>`. Compiler does a "wildcard capture" first to convert its type to `List<x> for some x`. Usually this is more informative and helpful. But not in your case. It drives type inference to think that `T=List<x>`, but `ListAttribute` does not extend `Attribute<List<x>>`

You can provide explicit type arguments to work around it

```
ctx.<List<?>, ListAttribute>put(ListAttribute.class, list);
      (T)      (A)
```

Comment: This solution satisfies the compiler but not the pattern which was initially created  to avoid verbose hints like type casts and explicit type argument.

Comment: @iterator - your original code now compiles in java8 with different inference rules. however, it's possible that it should have worked in java7 too but there was a bug in javac. Not sure.