# Generics Object assignment in java

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am getting compilation error for following code . ? means accepts any type of thing we assigned. I have Object type  and passes Object type. But I am getting compilation error why ?

```
NavigableSet<?> set = new TreeSet<Object>();
set.add(new Object());
```

Comment: @Sanjeev> The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type Set<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do generics of generics work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449799/how-do-generics-of-generics-work)

Comment: it means you cannot add anything to the set but you would be able to read from it. read java generics

Answer (score 4):

For the variable `NavigableSet<?>` , the compiler only knows that it's a `NavigableSet`, but doesn't know the type, so no object is safe to add.

For example, this could be the code:

```
NavigableSet<?> set = new TreeSet<String>(); // ? could be String
set.add(new Object()); // can't add Object to a Set<String>
```

Answer (score 0):

You loose the concrete type of your variable using `<?>` so the add can't work.

So you need to write:

```
NavigableSet<Object> set = new TreeSet<Object>();
set.add(new Object());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `NavigableSet<?> set` then your method add looks like `add(? arg)`. Java can not retrieve the type form `?`.

This is related to principle [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

And to solve it just use `super` as wildcard.

`NavigableSet<? super Object> set = new TreeSet<>();`

Answer (score 0):

The type is not knowable at compile time, for type `?`. We use `?` when the method does not depend on the type. Because the `add` method depends on the type, `?` is not a good fit for this.

The Java compiler will attempt to find a method signature that matches the method name, the number and type of the arguments provided. So let's do the same with yours.

```
name: add
number of arguments: 1
type: ? // Your issue.
```

However, `NavigableSet` does not have a method that matches this criteria, hence why no method is found.