# Generics type parameters and method calling

Tags: java

I have `I_class` with type parameters I and D:

```
class I_class<I extends I_class<I,D>, D extends D_class<I,D>>
```

I also have `X_class` with the same type parameters:

```
class X_class<I extends I_class<I,D>, D extends D_class<I,D>>
```

`X_class` has the method:

```
public D produceDeliver(I item) {...}
```

But when I try to call this method from `I_class`:

```
X_class<I, D> x_object = ...    

public D produceDeliver(){ 
         D deliver = x_object.produceDeliver(this);
         ...
```

I get this error message:

> The method produceDeliver(I) in the type X_class< I,D > is
>   not applicable for the arguments (I_class< I,D >)

I don't understand the non-equivalence between I and I_class< I,D >, since I extends I_class< I,D >

Comment: What does the D_class look like?

Comment: @Jeff D_class signature is the same to I and X classes

Comment: Who says `this` is of type `I`?

Comment: `I` extends `I_class` but `I_class` does not extend `I`. What you're trying to do is equivalent to assigning an `Object` to a variable of type `String`.

Comment: That's right @Jorn and if he is sure they're compatible he needs to cast.

Comment: The types are not compatible. Check out this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275665/java-generics-b-extends-baseb-does-not-match-extends-baseb)

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with more concrete names might be helpful:

```
class Building<B extends Building<B, X>, X extends Thing<B, X>> {
  Shop<B,X> s = new Shop<>();
  X makesError = s.getLocation(this);
}
class Shop<S extends Building<S, X>, X extends Thing<S, X>> {
   public X get_location(S shop) {...}
}
```

The problem is that when you are invoking getLocation, you are passing an argument of type Building. Not every instance of type Building is of type Shop.