# Capturing a Generic Type from an Implementation

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

In some Java code I have an interface like this:

```
interface A<T> {
    T produce();
    compare(T x, T y);
}
```

I have different implementations, such as:

```
class B extends A<int[]> {
    int[] produce() {...}
    compare(int[] x, int[] y) {...}
}
```

The issue is how to capture the implementation specific generic type. The following doesn't work:

```
A<T> a = new B();
T x = a.produce();
T y = a.produce();
a.compare(x, y);
```

Because of course the type `T` does not refer to what's inside `B`. (In fact it doesn't refer to anything.)

Is there a way to make `T` capture the generic type of `B`?

Comment: You already know it's `int[]`, why do you want a generic variable?

Comment: Sadly, Java is missing an identifier to let the compiler infer the type, like `auto` in C++ or `var` in C#, and there's no good way to keep this general other than calling `compare` in a single line (except Reflection)

Comment: Sotirios : Other implementations may use different types.

Comment: And they will still know. If you're writing `new B()` in your source code, you know that the generic type argument for `A` is `int[]`. Maybe your example is not indicative of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: If the assumption in my answer is correct, I think in the real world the instantiation of `a` and the subsequent operations would be separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can read between the lines a bit, I think what you are asking is how do you make this part in particular generic:

```
T x = a.produce();
T y = a.produce();
a.compare(x, y);
```

The answer is usually to "bind" the type parameter using a generic method:

```
private static <T> void produceAndCompare(A<T> a) {
    T x = a.produce();
    T y = a.produce();
    a.compare(x, y);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
produceAndCompare(new B());
```

And if it needs to be in a variable first:

```
A<?> a = getSomeA(); //could just return new B();
produceAndCompare(a);
```

Comment: Ah, so you "take advantage" of the methods ability to bind generics. Interesting.

Comment: @ThomasAhle: Exactly.  I gave a more detailed explanation in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449799/how-do-generics-of-generics-work/16451216#16451216.  Also, this Java tutorial goes into this topic fairly well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: It still seems strange that the only way to declare and capture a generic type, is in method definitions. If the functionality is already in Java, may there not be a way to capture the type inside the actual code?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: I agree, it would be pretty straightforward for them to have added this to the language.  However, I use generics extensively in the real world, and I could count on one hand the number of times where I wanted this, but thought that a helper method would have been inappropriate.  So perhaps it's justified to not bloat the language with the feature.