# Is it possible to define a class with <T extends Something> and also use this class as paramter of a method as class<?>

Tags: java, android, generics

I saw a code in android that defines the following class:

```
android.widget.AdapterView<T extends android.widget.Adapter>
```

and also has the following interface:
**AdapterView.OnItemClickListener** which contains the following method to be implemented:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

I can't understand how the first parameter works, if **AdapterView** was defined with constraint (  extneds...)
How can it be a quiestion mark if it must be Adatper or something that derived from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `AdapterView<T extends android.widget.Adapter>` requires that the concrete type used to create its instance extends Adapter and thus Adapter methods can be used inside.

Interface declaration (which actually doesn't have to be inside this class) accepts parameter `AdapterView<?>` where `?` is so called wildcard. It means that type is unknown and can be anything.

For class it makes difference because its implementation will actually do something with type that is passed as generic parameter. You can define upper or lower bound on the type, but can't use unknown type in this case.

In case of interface - it is not a generic itself. Also, it's method is not generic, but accepts `AdapterView` of any type. Because of the wildcard any `AdapterView` can be passed to `onItemLongClick`.
This is because `AdapterView<A>` is not a subclass of `AdapterView<B>`, even if `A` is a subclass of `B`.
It is explained here (with example):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

You may want to read more about Java generics here:
[How do generics of generics work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449799/how-do-generics-of-generics-work/16451216#16451216)

or/and here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: thanks a lot, but why are you saying in isn't important in the interface. If the person who implement the interface will use the AdapaterView<?> method (for example the method getAdapter()), to which type of reference can the return value be assigned?. In what is it different from using getAdapter method inside the AdapterView class?

Comment: I edited my answer. It needed correction and I used a 'thought shortcut'. I hope it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: thanks i'm on my way to shift. I will read your answer later and approve it (i hope) after it. thanks!!!

Comment: isn't it more reasonable that instead of AdapaterView<?> it will be ApaterView<? extends  Adaper> or AdapterView<T extneds Adapter>? because the Type inside the brakcets should be an Adapter that related to the ListView, GridView, etc?

Comment: Hi, sorry, was off the grid for some time. Unbounded wildcards (```<?>```) are reifiable types in Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6 - check both 4.7 and 4.6). In this case type parameter of AdapterView will be known at runtime as Adapter (check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1). To wrap it up - in this case ```?``` and ```? extends Adapter``` will be equivalent.